# Online receipt change in 4.7: Wrong template is being used

Tags: contributions, receipts, issues

We upgraded to 4.7 and using WP 4.4.1.
The Online receipt for payments has changed -- something is telling the system to use the summary receipt and I can not find out what it is.

See pics.
How can we get the full receipt back or is there something else wrong?

**Before update:**

[image: Before update]

**After update:**

[image: After Update]

Comment: I am running into a similar issue on receipts from 4.7 -- will be watching this thread and post back if I find anything myself.

Comment: One of my tech guys just sent this to me - "Something is telling the system to use the summary receipt and I can not find out what it is."

Comment: Also...  "The code in the receipt messages area is correct besides the fact that they use && plus and in the same if statement. However the the parameters being sent to the receipt system are causing it to use the wrong template.


That big chunk of code is basically a long list of receipt templates with conditions set for each one. The wrong conditions are being sent and thus the wrong template is being used."

Comment: Any updates on this? I am having a similar issue. Some of the tokens seem to have different values now (e.g. $contributeMode differs and $trxn_id comes in empty, even though it gets correctly recorded in the DB).

Comment: Thanks for your post but this would be better posted as a comment as it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3060)

Comment: Which code/files are your tech guys looking at?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3060)

Comment: This is what I was being told.  The "code" that was being passed to the email was the wrong code, so the email was displaying the "Summary" receipt instead of the detail receipt.  I'm not sure what they did to "fix" this.  I think they hacked it somehow.  Sorry.  That is all I know at this point.

Comment: Any chance your tech guy is willing to set up an account here and answer your question? If it is a bug in the core code it would be helpful to everyone if we can identify and fix it.

Comment: He is now...  John Webster  - here's his post - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9475/credit-card-receipt-after-4-7-update

Answer (score 1):

You can update your CiviCRM ticket to tell them that $contributeMode is being set to "notify" for credit card payments, which is why credit card information isn't being printed.

Comment: Hi @JohnWebster, I think the issue is that the new receipt does not show the details on the two line items, but puts both the Professional Dues and Chapter Dues into a single amount with no details.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a bug report in JIRA for this.

Comment: The Event part of CiviCRM is working fine.  Only the Payment/Contribution part is the problem.  And how/where do I submit the bug report?

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18027