# Credit Card Receipt after 4.7 update

Tags: receipts, authorize.net, 4.7

Prior to updating to CiviCRM 4.7 our customers received receipts that included:

- Membership fees with each item listed separately with a description
  and price.
- The Transaction number
- The Billing Name and Address
- The Credit Card Information (only last four of credit card)

After we installed 4.7 this information stopped displaying on the receipt.

I have reviewed the receipt template. I did not see anything that should change this.

Is there a new setting that I am missing to display the transaction details?

Comment: This question is similar: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9354/online-receipt-change-in-4-7-wrong-template-is-being-used

Comment: Did you have a customisation on your system that provided the last 4 digits of the credit card? I don't recall seeing that before

Comment: $credit_card_number automatically masks all but the last four numbers when displaying a credit card number in the message template.

Comment: What was your previous version?

Comment: Our previous version was 4.6.9

Comment: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18027

Comment: Are you talking about cc transaction made through a civicrm webpage?

Comment: $contributeMode is being set to "notify" for credit card payments, which is why credit card information isn't being printed.

Comment: Civicrm 4.7.7 WordPress Where does one set **$contributeMode** in the Civicrm menu? Or did you have to change the code to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This fix in [JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18027) is meant to have fixed this problem